# Start Activity on Reboot Only

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, bootcompleted

Basically I am trying to make an activity containing a button which reboots the device and after the reboot returns to the same activity.

**I understand that this question may get confused with others about rebooting the device, but that is not the focus of this question as I can get the device to reboot fine.**

I have made the button reboot the device but the only way I can get it to start the activity after it's finished rebooting is to register a broadcast receiver for `BOOT_COMPLETED` in the manifest. The trouble is that this method starts the activity every time the device boots which is undesirable. When I register the receiver on the button click listener it does not start the activity after the reboot.

I was wondering if there might be an extra in `BOOT_COMPLETED` that I could use to decide if it had been purposefully rebooted.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just save an integer corresponding to device purposely being rebooted through your activity. Use `SharedPreference` for the same. On reboot, in your `broadcast receiver`, check if the value is set. If it is set, start your activity, otherwise, let it go.

**EDIT** :

**Always, unset** this value when reboot is complete and your Activity is in front.

Comment: This is the way to go

Comment: nice answer. Just for a better explaination: ALWAYS, on activity start, set the value to 0(for example) and when you reboot from app set it to 1(for example). On reboot, if it is 1, start the Activity :)

Comment: @Shubham no prob, just to avoid future questions about it..:)

Answer (score 0):

Your XML should be stored in a file named AndroidManifest.xml, not manifest.java.

Another reason your code is not being run, might be that your App is installed on external storage (sdcard). BOOT_COMPLETE is sent to applications before external storage is mounted. So if application is installed to external storage it won't receive BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast message.

If that isn't the problem, there is already a very good description of how to get boot completed receivers working on Android.

[Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)

Comment: It is installed on internal as there is no external storage on this device. Also the Manifest is an XML file. Thanks for the answer though!